# Jorgen's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm making some notes on minimal surfaces for undergrad and master students and i'm writing the proof of Bernstein's problem by elementary means, not geometrical-analytic ones. I proved that the problem es equivalent to prove that any $C^2$ function globally defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with hessian equal to $1$ must be quadratic polynomial. Apparently this is something called Jorgen's theorem but i cannot find any reference beyond the original paper, which is in german. Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: I have typed a proof  in French a long  time ago. I can send the pdf if you are interested.

Comment: I no longer have Osserman's little book, but what proof does he have? The proof in Spivak, Volume 4 (pp. 112-115) looks like it uses only a tiny bit of complex analysis.

Comment: @LetacGérard I really apreciate it, but i don't speak any french :(

Comment: The proof is one  and a half page in latex. May be I will type it in English on a rainy day.